# Syntax error after adding trrigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers

I'm trying to create a simple trigger but it gives me a syntax error

```
CREATE TRIGGER `delete_image`
 AFTER DELETE ON `product_images` 
 FOR EACH ROWS 
 BEGIN `enter code here`
  DELETE FROM `cart_items` 
 END;
```

Comment: for each row - and every statement must be terminated and you need to set delimiters, NB all cart_items records will be deleted with this code - is that what you intended? and what is `enter code here` supposed to do?

Comment: My code is to remove data from cart_item after deleting item from product_images

Comment: Then I suggest you review  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html where you will find an example of a delete trigger and be a bit more selective in the delete